# How can I select a xml node that has comma separated values to see a particular value exists in the list using xpath?

Tags: vb.net, xpath

Suppose I have an the following XML

```
<Invoices>
  <Invoice>
    <ID>1234</ID>
    <Description>Product Description</Description>
    <SubmittedBy>2,45,50</SubmittedBy>
  </Invoice>
  <Invoice>
    <ID>1234</ID>
    <Description>Product Description</Description>
    <SubmittedBy>2,4</SubmittedBy>
  </Invoice>
<Invoices>
```

I want to select those Invoices which have been submitted by '2'. How can in do it using xpath select string in VB.Net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very similar to matching HTML classes with XPath.

Possible positions of `2` are:

- beginning (`2,...`)
- middle (`...,2,...`)
- end (`..., 2`)
- only number (`2`)

To find all of these while disallowing other numbers *containing* 2, concatenate the search string with colons at the beginning and end and use contains.

```
//Invoice[contains(concat(',', SubmittedBy, ','), ',2,')]
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this works in VB.net but you can use this xpath:

```
 //Invoice[contains(SubmittedBy, ',2,')]|//Invoice[starts-with(SubmittedBy, '2,')]|//Invoice[SubmittedBy= '2']|//Invoice[ends-with(SubmittedBy, ',2')]
```

- first finds 2 anywhere (contains)
- second starts with 2 (starts-with)
- third equals 2 (=)
- and last one ends with 2 (ends-with)

xpath tested

Answer (score 0):

The XPath below will return all `Invoice` nodes where `SubmittedBy` starts with '2':

```
//Invoice[starts-with(SubmittedBy, 2)]
```

but the above will return nodes that start with '21', which is probably not what you want. This is better:

```
//Invoice[starts-with(SubmittedBy, "2,")]
```